# Restarting app after pause with onTouchEvent in surfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

Hi I am new at programming with Android, I have been watching a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB1F9A9707CDD9EE9) about game programming in Android, the problem is that this specific course was left at mid terms, so the game isn't finished, so I have tried to add some stuff myself. Just about the begining og my new journey I have been working in a problem that can't be fixed by myself so I try here if someone can help me with it.

The problem is the visual part of the game, I have a *surfaceView* and also an event *onTouchEvent*. The problem appears when I pause the game (method *onPause* from the activity) it happens that the *surfaceHolder* gets destroyed (from the method *surfaceDestroyed*) but for not getting in troubles I have to stop the thread (*GameLoopThread*) which updates the game. When the game is unpaused it calls the *onResume*
method and it creates a new *surfaceFolder* and initializes the *GameLoopeThread* Thread.

The problem I have is that after calling the method *onResume()* and re-initialize everything, the event *onTouchEvent* from the surfaceView stops working, so on click it doesnt work and after a while I get a message saying that the application doesn't respond and I get to choose between wait (nothing happens) or force the closure of the application.

I leave you the code from the surfaceView (some stuff isn't necessary by now, and some stuff is commented for try outs).

```
package net.balanze.tutorialjuego;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
/*
* See audio with ToneGenerator, MediaPlayer y SoundPool.
*/
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

private SurfaceHolder holder; 
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread; 
private List<Sprite> sprites=new ArrayList<Sprite>(); 
private long lastClick; 
private Bitmap bmpBlood; 
private List<TempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<TempSprite>(); 
private int puntos=0;
private Paint paint;
/*
 * iniciamos sndPool con un maximo de 16 flujos simultanios
 * el audio sera del flujo musical, (el ultimo parametro no
 * funciona asi que pongo 0 que es el conversor por defecto).
 */
private SoundPool sndPool = new SoundPool(16, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
private int sonidoMalo;
/*private int x=0; 
private int xSpeed=1;*/

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
            boolean intento=true;
            while(intento){
                try {
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("ERROR --> Problema al destruir la view.");
                }
                intento=false;
            }
            //gameLoopThread=null;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
             createSprites();
            /*
             * La asignacion de los Sprites se hace aqui ya que 
             * para calcular las posiciones en las que empieza cada
             * sprite necesitamos conocer el alto y el ancho de la 
             * pantalla y si no se acabo de crear la view no conocemos
             * sus dimensiones. 
             */
             gameLoopThread=(!gameLoopThread.isAlive())?new GameLoopThread(devolverVista()):gameLoopThread;
            if(!gameLoopThread.isRunning()){
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    bmpBlood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blood1);
    sonidoMalo=sndPool.load(context, R.raw.baddeath, 1);
    paint=new Paint();
    paint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
}
/**
 * <p><b>private void createSprites()</b></p>
 * <p>Añade a al array list sprites todos los sprites que veremos
 * en pantalla.</p>
 */
private void createSprites(){
    // establecemos el grafico que queremos pintar.
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad1, false));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad2, false));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad3, false));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad4, false));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad5, false));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad6, false));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good1, true));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good2, true));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good3, true));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good4, true));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good5, true));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good6, true));
}
/**
 * <p><b>private Sprite createSprite(int Resource)</b></p>
 * <p>Devuelve un sprite con la imagen que se le pasa como recurso.</p>
 * @param Resource Recurso de imagen que queremos pintar en el Sprite.
 * @return Sprite creador con imagen pasada.
 */
private Sprite createSprite(int Resource, boolean esBueno){
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Resource);
    return new Sprite(this, bmp, esBueno);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText("Puntuacion: "+puntos, 0, 30, paint);
    for(int i=temps.size()-1; i>=0; i--) temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
    for(Sprite sprite:sprites){
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
     if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastClick>300){
        lastClick=System.currentTimeMillis();
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            for(int i=sprites.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
                Sprite sprite=sprites.get(i);
                if(sprite.isColision(x, y)){
                    if(!sprite.esBueno()) sndPool.play(sonidoMalo, 1.0f, 1.0f, 5, 0, 1.0f);
                    puntos+=sprite.puntuar();
                    sprites.remove(sprite);
                    temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpBlood));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //return true;
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
/**
 * <p><b>public boolean quedanMalos()</b><P>
 * <p>Devuelve verdadero si quedan sprites de enemigos y falso en caso contrario.</p>
 * @return true si quedan enemigos, false si solo quedan sprites buenos.
 */
public boolean quedanMalos(){
    boolean soloBuenos=true;
    for(int i=0; i<sprites.size() && soloBuenos; i++)     soloBuenos=sprites.get(i).esBueno();
    return !soloBuenos;        
}
/**
 * <p><b>public void pause()</b></p>
 * <p>Pausa el juego, porque pausa el gameLoop.</p>
 */
public void pause(){
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
    boolean intento=true;
    //synchronized (gameLoopThread) {
        while(intento){
            try{
                gameLoopThread.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR --> No se pudo para el gameLoop.");
            }
            intento=false;
        }
    //}
    gameLoopThread=null;
}
public void resume(){
    if(holder.isCreating()){
        gameLoopThread=(!gameLoopThread.isAlive())?new GameLoopThread(this):gameLoopThread;
        if(!gameLoopThread.isRunning()){
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }
    }
}
private GameView devolverVista(){
    return this;
}
```

}

Thank you very much for your help. If you need anything more from the code or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know if you still need help, but here goes;

First of all, do some debugging to check if when you return you are getting values or if your onTouch is even getting triggered by using a breakpoint there (although form reading your post I guess you've already done that).

Also try to see if the view/viewgroup around your surfaceview is getting any touches (give the layout/view an id and an ontouchlistener and breakpoint that).

What I do in my thread-run surfaceview is I override the ontouch of the surfaceview-view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return thread.doTouchEvent(event);
}
```

and in my thread I handle the touch event:

```
boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) 
        {
               (detect ondown etc, do something and return true/false)
            }
       }
```

This seems to handle things properly after a onResume. Be sure to handle your thread properly, though (oncreate, ondestroy etc).

BTW, to handle input flooding I have this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    /*touchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();       
    if (oldTouchAction == -1)
    {
        lastTouchTime = touchTime;
        oldTouchAction = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);

        super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(32);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return true;
    }
    else
    {           
        if (oldTouchAction == (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK))
        {
            if ((touchTime - lastTouchTime) > 35)
            {
                lastTouchTime = touchTime;

                super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

                return true;
            }
            lastTouchTime = touchTime;
        }
        else
        {
            lastTouchTime = touchTime;
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

           return true;
        }
    }       
    lastTouchTime = touchTime;*/
    if (touchBool)
    {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(32);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This stops the activity from slowing down from too many touch events (the touchBool is just something I use to prevent an event being triggered twice later on when the game is won/lost; when the game is won/lost and the event is triggered by touching the screen touchBool is set to false. I also have a method in the surfaceview which sets it to true/false which is triggered in the surrounding activity's onresume/onpause).

Anyway, I hope this helps and good luck!